# GitLab CI : merge or replace cache?

Tags: caching, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using GitLab CI.

I have 2 jobs in the build stage that build differently my app. The 2 jobs upload a cache for the branch. I use the compiled sources to launch some tests in the test stage.

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew build --build-cache --quiet
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
     - "*/build"

build_with_different_conf:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew buildDiff --build-cache --quiet
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
     - "*/build"

Test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew test --build-cache
```

In my example, the job build_with_different_conf take more time to finish.

My question is :  Is the last finishing build job upload the cache and replace the cache from the first build job or is it merging files whith the precedent job ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, why do you use `cache` for a branch, and what do you mean by that.

Give some code .yml example.

Comment: I edited to add more context

Comment: First of all i think you mussuse the cache, in this context you want to use artefacts to transport your build results. Cache is mostley used to transport some dependencies or other stuff that dont move too often, like npm node_modules

Comment: you will probably want to use a differnet "storage/image manager" for your builds - for example, if you use docker containers - push them to container registry, artifactory for jars...

Comment: I would recomend to spend some time on `artifact` documentation.
From what i understund you want to `build` in one job, than use the build result to accelerate `test`. `Build1` and `build2` are just diferent entry points.
Is that correct ?
Or would you rahter have `build1` than use result to accelerte `build2` and `test` ?

Comment: @LukaszKruszyna We just compile the classes in the build job. We just need the .class in order to launch tests. We don't need the JAR (or the WAR). It is for that purpose that I push the build directory in the cache.

Comment: Later we will made a complete build job that make the complete WAR. This one will be available as a artifact and I will use it in the deploy job.

Comment: To answer to your last question : YES build1 and build2 are different and produce different build/ directory. I need the build1 to accelerate the next jobs. For the moment what I do is to putt the build directory of build1 in a cache named with the branch name and using it in all next jobs. The build from build2 is cached in another cache and used only in this job

Comment: Still, your `build` job result can be artifact of `.classes` than this artifact can have lifespan of fiew min/hours. Than using this compiled `.classes` in folowing job you can build your `war`. Your folowing jobs just have to depend on precedent, this way they transfer artifacts.
I will still state on my first comment, cache can be missused for it, but its not its primal role.

Comment: For example, we are using the cache for the gradle distribution that is downloaded from the wrapper if not present. This seems to be a good use for the cache?
It's good to know too that the build/ directory, if present, make the build job faster. It do not recompile the code that do not change. Can I do this with artifacts?
Thanks for all your tips @LukaszKruszyna :+1:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
build:
  stage: build
```

Same stage jobs runs in parallel.

```
cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
     - "*/build"
```

Cache files are managed by `cache:key`. It means if you're using same `cache:key` for  different jobs they'll share same `cache.zip` file across jobs even you're defining different `cache:paths`. If you're using same key, but different path then your cache won't be effective, because of every job will overwrite `cache.zip` file with different path contents.

In your case you're using same `cache:key` across different jobs.

```
cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
     - "*/build"
```

It means last finished job will overwrite the `cache.zip` file not merge and will be used for next job and subsequent pipeline jobs with same key defined.

Bonus:

```
Test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew test --build-cache
```

Also beware that if this job requires `*/build` directory contents to exist, you have to be careful and better to use artifacts instead. Cache doesn't always exist and it's provided as best effort delivery.

For example I use gitlab ci's cache like this.

```
nodejs_test:
  stage: test
  image: node:12.13-alpine
  before_script:
    - npm install
  script:
    - yarn test
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        # New cache key will be computed on each package.json change.
        - package.json
    paths:
      - node_modules/

nodejs_build:
  stage: build
  image: node:12.13-alpine
  before_script:
    # In case if we miss cache, we can simply install packages again.
    # If cache is there npm install won't download them again.
    - npm install
  script:
    - yarn build
  cache:
    policy: pull        # totally optional
    key:
      files:
        - package.json
      prefix: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - node_modules/
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are using global cache for gradle dependencies.
Then you want to have some kind of job, to job cache.

I would do it this way, more or less.

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

cache:
  paths:
    - <your_gradle_cache>

build_classes:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew build --build-cache --quiet
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1d
    paths:
      - <your_build_dir>
    
build_war:
  stage: build
  dependencies:
    - build_classes
  script:
    - ./gradlew buildDiff --build-cache --quiet
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1w
    paths:
      - <path_to_your_war>

test_classes:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - build_war
  script:
    - ./gradlew test --build-cache

test_war:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - build_war
  script:
    - test # some kind of test to assure your war is in good condition
```

In this configuration:

```
build_classes --[.classes]--> build_war -> [.war]
 |                 |
[.classes]       [.war]
 |                 |
 V                 V
test_classes    test_war
```

PS. Don't forget you can use `shell` (or whatever your runner's os) to debug, understand more about this. You can put `ls -la` all over the place.

Comment: Yes it's true that at the beginning I was using `ls` and `pwd` everywhere to understand the container structure. It can be good to double check the cache content ;)
For the use of artifacts, I'm not sure. I will defintely use the war as an artifact and use it in the deploy stage but the build directory can improve the build for the next pipeline in the same branch. Correct me if I'm wrong but artifacts are more for using in the same pipeline. With the cache I can re-use it in my next branch pipeline to accelerate the build.
Thanks for all the tips ;)

Comment: In this case `${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}` should work. for the cache key, witch should be branch related.

Well, either you define it globaly, this way whole ci uses it.
Or you leave it per job, this way only one sequence of jobs make use of it.

This may be more `gradle` related, on where i have not much to say.